# reference textViewResourceId from the arrayadapter : android

Tags: android, textview, android-arrayadapter

I wanted to update my layout from

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="16sp" >
</TextView>
```

To

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/maintitle"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="@string/choose_contact"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/contentlist"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="16sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

So I can have that header text. Now, I was using

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, arraylist));
```

To send my data, but I'm now getting a "ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a view". So I'm trying to use a different constructor, namely

```
ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, T[] objects)
```

to reference the specific ID of my textview, but I haven't found out how to do so.
I thought it would be something along the lines of

```
R.layout.list_item.id_of_my_txtview
```

How do I reference the textview id to use this constructor?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reference your TextView ID as any other View ID: R.id.id_of_the_view. Reference: [XML Layouts - ID](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#id).

Code will look like this:

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.contentlist, arraylist));
```